# Data type issue creating an Excel file using the ACE OLEDB Provider

Tags: excel, ssis, ms-jet-ace

I'm using the ACE OLE DB provider and an Execute SQL Task in order to create an Excel file.
The connection string I'm using is like this one:

```
Data Source=C:\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";
```

and the SQL command is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE [Query] (
[ProductAssemblyID] Numeric,
[ComponentID] Numeric,
[ComponentDesc] String,
[TotalQuantity] Numeric,
[StandardCost] Currency,
[ListPrice] Currency,
[BOMLevel] Numeric,
[RecursionLevel] Numeric)
```

Then I'm using an Excel Destination to populate the file. When I open the resultin file, all columns are Text columns and numbers are stored as text.
Where am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I usually go about a task like yours:

1. Create an Excel file with the columns you want
2. Add an **Excel Data Connection** to the new file
3. Create a **Data Flow**
4. Add an **OLE DB Source** and `SELECT ... FROM ...`
5. Add an **Excel Destination** and set to Excel connection
6. Map the columns as needed
7. In the **Advanced Editor** of the **Excel Destination**, set the columns data types

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried to change the Excel Destination External Columns data types, but the Excel Destination shows a warning saying that metadata are out of synchronization and the resulting Excel file has always text columns... I also checked the Excel Destination Input Columns data types and they are assigned in the right way. I can't figure out a solution...

Comment: A not very elegant thing to try is have a "dummy" row with data as you need it (i.e. 7/19/13 in a date field). It's kind of kludge, and I only used in a data source, but it's something to try. I had used it when SSIS was casting a column as a string and I needed it to be an int.

Comment: Yes, I knew this workaround. The only problem is that I have to create the Excel file at runtime, so I can't use templates with hidden rows. I just tried to use the Jet provider and all works fine! So SSIS manage the ACE one in a buggy way!!! :(

Comment: I've just found this connect item:
[Excel Data Types from SSIS](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/477970/excel-data-types-from-ssis). The bug still exists in SQL Server 2012...

Comment: That's too bad about the bug still existing. Because once you need to run the SSIS package on a 64 bit machine, using Jet is going to be another headache.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for days. Here's what I've found:
With the default Extended Properties (EXCEL 12.0 XML; HDR=YES), NONE of these providers work (i.e. they create text fields instead of numbers, dates etc.):

- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 (Microsoft Excel 2007-2010)
- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 (Microsoft Excel 2013)
- Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 (Microsoft Excel 2016)

As mentioned by @lucazav, choosing the older Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider (if you have it) does work. This is what is used if you choose "Excel 97-2003". However, if you need to deploy to a production machine or otherwise don't have the old JET driver, you might find that it's not available anymore, doesn't work on 64-bit machines etc.

But, you **DO NOT NEED** to install the older JET driver. I was able to make ACE.OLEDB.12.0 work by simply changing the Extended Properties.

Change

```
Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES
```

to

```
Excel 8.0;HDR=YES
```

Also, you'll want to set your filename extension to be .xls instead of .xlsx. Otherwise, when you open the file with Excel, it will complain about the extension not matching the actual file type.

The HDR is optional but I need headers so I use it. I don't think the casing on 'Excel' matters.

I was clued into this solution by the Install Instruction on the Microsoft Download Page for [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (which is how you get the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider).

[image]

"Excel 8.0" is also the default Extended Properties when using JET.